# How to remember a Session if the user has visited the 'splash/landing' page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this really simple C# to redirect users to a splash page when they enter the `/default.aspx` homepage:

```
if (Session["homepageHoarding"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("/homepage-hoardings/limited-offer.aspx");
}
```

On that 'splash' page: `/homepage-hoardings/limited-offer.aspx`, there is a link to return to the 'normal' homepage, which of course is: `/default.aspx`

But it redirects again, thinking that the session doesn't exist, which it doesn't.

How do I get it so that once they've seen the Splash page it remembers that they've seen it? I can't use a global because my terrible web-hosts don't allow it :-(

Many thanks :-)

Comment: Although it's a bit much for this situation, you could try setting a cookie

Comment: Whats about adding 'Session["splashVisited"] = true'?

Comment: What have you tried? Currently your question boils down to `My website behaves as expected but I want something different`. On a side-note: Is it really necessary to redirect the user? Seems a bit annoying from a UX viewpoint. Wouldn't a regular in-site popup be obtrusive enough?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer that is all I have tried at present. I'm unsure (as a Cookie has just been mentioned) what the best way is to achieve this is.

Comment: Where are you setting the value for Session["homepageHoarding"] ? seems like it's always null.

Comment: Avoid using session altogether. It doesn't scale and means that you're holding state on the server. Use a cookie to indicate that the user has performed this action.

Comment: You could do it pure clientside, settings a localStorage item that it was already visited.

Comment: You should have a backup plan for users that have cookies and/or JS disabled.

Comment: @Brunis The redirect is happening on the server.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer i know, that's why i asked him to move it to the clientside where he can control it

Comment: @Brunis Oh ... right, sorry I totally missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, use cookies:

```
bool userVisited = false;
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];
if (cookie == null)
{
    cookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
    cookie.Values.Add("userVisitedSplash", true);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30); //<-- Sets the expiration date
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    this.Page.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
} else{
     userVisited = cookie.Values["userVisitedSplash"]
}
if(userVisited){
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
} else{
    Response.Redirect("/homepage-hoardings/limited-offer.aspx");
}
```